Retrieving the type of array item through Items[number] instead of Item. How bad is it for performance of typechecking?
Suppose in one file I have
export type Item = {
  foo: string
  bar: number
}

export type Items = Item[]

and in other file I do
// notice that here we get the type of `item` from the type of array
const fnArray = (item: Items[number]) => {
  return item.foo
}

instead of
const fnItem = (item: Item) => {
  return item.foo
}

Did anyone test the actual impact of one approach vs another on typechecking performance?
Using tsc --generateTrace shows some slowing down, but it's hard to make any conclusions, so maybe someone has more definitive results using tools like already mentioned tsc --generateTrace or @ark/attest.

• A performance question like this might not be possible to answer; what do you mean by "constantly"? A bunch of extra indexed accesses might slow down the compilation time, but without something concrete it's hard to say, and I wouldn't even know how to tell if an answer were correct. It's not like there's a worldwide code analysis of this already. Are you asking us to perform such an analysis of public code bases? Please [edit] to clarify your metric for judging an answer.
